# Getting Meta events from MusicTrack

Tags: macos, core-audio, coremidi

I want MetaEvent information from the music track. How do I get it? I am interested in the trackname and Instrument name of the track.

I see MusicTrack has newMetaEvent method but not a way to get it. This ofcourse is in Core Audio & OS X.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You use a [MusicEventIterator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/MusicEventIterator_Reference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009333) to iterate through the track events, getting the eventInfo and testing for the eventType you are seeking. Some refs from the docs below. Example code of how to use a `MusicEventIterator` is [here.](http://www.techques.com/question/1-9689914/How-to-get-access-to-MusicTracks-in-a-MusicSequence)

---

```
OSStatus MusicEventIteratorGetEventInfo (
   MusicEventIterator  inIterator,
   MusicTimeStamp      *outTimeStamp,
   MusicEventType      *outEventType,
   const void          **outEventData,
   UInt32              *outEventDataSize
);
```

---

**Music Event Types**

*MIDI and other music event types, used by music event iterator functions.*

```
enum {
   kMusicEventType_NULL = 0,
   kMusicEventType_ExtendedNote,
   kMusicEventType_ExtendedTempo,
   kMusicEventType_User,
   kMusicEventType_Meta,
   kMusicEventType_MIDINoteMessage,
   kMusicEventType_MIDIChannelMessage,
   kMusicEventType_MIDIRawData,
   kMusicEventType_Parameter,
   kMusicEventType_AUPreset,
};
typedef UInt32 MusicEventType;
```